# Error in JavaScript while using in Cucumber Selenium with Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, automated-tests

I am trying to select a dropdown using the below code in Selenium ruby with cucumber framework.I have included a Javascript to select the value.

```
When(/^user selects year as (\d+)$/) do |arg1|

  $driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByName("param[start_year]")[0].value=arg1;')

end
```

But I am getting an error like this.Please help me resolve

```
arg1 is not defined (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit of JavaScript you are executing has the variable `arg1` hard coded in. The script will see this as a JavaScript variable - and as no such variable has been defined within the JavaScript space, you get an error.

From the rest of the code, I assume you actually want to pass the value of the `arg1` variable defined in the Ruby space, into the JavaScript code. I'd suggest you try this:

```
When(/^user selects year as (\d+)$/) do |arg1|
  $driver.execute_script(%Q<document.getElementsByName("param[start_year]")[0].value="#{arg1}";>)
end
```

Note that I've used the [`%Q` text delimiter](http://blog.brzezinka.eu/webmaster-tips/ruby/alternative-stringss-delimiter-for-ruby-on-rails) so that `#{}` text insertion can be combined with text including double quotes (`"`)